# Como efetuar o submit de um form com OnsenUI e AngularJS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, onsen

Como proceder para efetuar um submit com o **Onsen UI** + **AngularJS**?

Tenho o seguinte **ons-page**:

```html
<ons-page ng-controller="LoginController">
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">Acesso ao Sistema</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <form action="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")" method="post" id="loginForm" 
      class="login-form">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "")

        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
            @class = "text-input--underbar", 
            placeholder = "E-mail", 
            autofocus = "autofocus" 
        } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)

        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { 
            @class = "text-input--underbar", 
            placeholder = "Senha" 
        })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        <br><br>
        <ons-button modifier="large" class="login-button">Login</ons-button>
        <br><br>
        <ons-button modifier="quiet" class="forgot-password">
            Esqueceu sua senha?
        </ons-button>
    </form>
</ons-page>

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Static/js/controllers/loginController.js"></script>
}
```

Os plugins renderizam na ordem necessária:

```html
<script src="/Static/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Static/vendor/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>    
<script src="/Static/js/controllers/loginController.js"></script>
```

Conteúdo de `loginController.js`:

```js
(function () {
    var module = ons.bootstrap("loginModule", ["onsen"]);
    //module.controller("AppController", function ($scope) { });
    //module.controller("MainController", function ($scope) { });
    module.controller("LoginController", function ($scope) { });
})();
```

Comment: Você quer submeter e processar o login via AJAX ou simplesmente submeter o form da forma normal?

Comment: @Alfred, a princípio a forma tradicional. Não sei como fazer pois o OnsenUI não gera um button submit. Grato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A OnsenUI não tem um botão submit, mas você pode mascarar isso:

Adicione ao seu form um name:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")" method="post"
id="loginForm" class="login-form" name="loginForm">
```

Altere o seu controller para:

```
module.controller("LoginController", function ($scope) { 
    $scope.login = function() {
        $scope.loginForm.submit();
    }
});
```

E o botão de login:

```
<ons-button modifier="large" class="login-button" ng-click="login()">Login</ons-button>
```

Comment: Infelizmente estou recebendo o erro: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined`. Sabe o que poderia ser? Grato!

Comment: Eu não percebi que seu form não tem um name. Adicione ao seu form name="loginForm": `<form action="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")" method="post" id="loginForm" 
      class="login-form" name="loginForm">`

Comment: Na verdade, mesmo com name continuei recebendo o erro `TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined`. Então mesmo sem o atributo `name` na `tag form`, fazendo `loginForm.submit()`, sem usar `$scope`, funcionou.

Comment: Que curioso isso @JamesTK. O código que postei para você funcionou e é a forma que sempre usei nesse sentido. O erro se justificaria caso seu form estivesse fora do Controller, mas nesse caso ele é parte do Controller. Mas, se você conseguiu fazer funcionar, que bom! Vou dar uma estudada em relação ao que ocorreu com você, de qualquer forma.